# difference between stack, ensemble & stack ensemble steps in MLJAR

Tags: python, machine-learning, ensemble-learning, automl, mljar

While experimenting with MLJar, I figured out in 'Compete' mode it uses the below 3 steps towards the end of the training:

```
stack
ensemble
stack ensemble
```

As stacking is a type of ensemble learning, how are the last 3 steps different? I tried reading the documentation but no specifics are mentioned: https://supervised.mljar.com/features/automl/#ensemble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of each ensemble type in [MLJAR AutoML](https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised) package is in [Algorithms section in the docs](https://supervised.mljar.com/features/algorithms/).

The docs for Ensemble is [here](https://supervised.mljar.com/features/algorithms/#ensemble). It is simple average of previous models. Models are selected until they improve the ensemble performance.

The docs for Stacked Algorithm is [here](https://supervised.mljar.com/features/algorithms/#stacked-algorithm). It is a model trained on original data plus stacked predictions of previous models.

The Stacked Ensemble is the Ensemble build from models trained on original data and models on stacked data (original+stacked predictions).

@mehul-gupta please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: By stacked predictions you mean 1) predictions by unstacked models on out-of-fold data. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.